# How to preg_grep on a particular number with different format in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of reference numbers that contain a dot, a dash and a search string of a reference number with dots, dashes stripped.

Now I want to retrieve the matching key in order to retrieve the number in its original state.

Looking for this reference number: 21230412003001

Inside array:

```
$ref_facetes = Array
(
    [212.30.41.20.03.001] => 8
    [3523.30.00] => 8
    [215.92.46.22.01.003] => 7
)
```

regex:

```
'/\/|\./'
```

Trying to grep it:

```
$key = preg_grep('/\/|\./', $search_para['refid'], $ref_facetes);
```

In order to retrieve the original writing style:

```
echo $ref_facetes[$key];

// should return: 212.30.41.20.03.001
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to create a new array with all the non-digit characters stripped from the original keys as keys and the original keys as values, which you can do with [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php), [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). Then you can just check to see if the search string exists as a key and if so, output the value:

```
$ref_keys = array_combine(array_map(function ($v) { 
    return preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $v);
}, array_keys($ref_facetes)), array_keys($ref_facetes));
echo isset($ref_keys[$search_para['refid']]) ? $ref_keys[$search_para['refid']] : 'not found';
```

Output:

```
212.30.41.20.03.001
```

If you are using PHP7 and up you can replace the last line with

```
echo $ref_keys[$search_para['refid']] ?? 'not found';
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/G7fqQ)